# How to avoid update_at change on migrations

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

When running TypeORM migrations and altering the values of columns in a table, it causes the auto generated `update_at` column to update.

I'm trying to avoid this as this change is a migration and is "not really" a change to the row.

The way I run this kind of migrations now is:

```js
await queryRunner.query(`
  UPDATE "table_name"
  SET "column_name"=value1
  WHERE "other_column"=value2
`)
```

The way I was able to avoid this behaviour is to change my migration to:

```js
await queryRunner.query(`
  UPDATE "table_name"
  SET "column_name"=value1,
      "update_at"="update_at"
  WHERE "other_column"=value2
`)
```

The problem with this solution is that I can not force other developers to use this method aside from Code Review and I would much rather have it done as an infrastructure for all migrations in the system.

Comment: Being SQL, developers could write anything without an easy way to enforce checks. Code review, set same date via repository, or an automatic test to check update has not changed seems most appropriate.